# display: none applies slow after page load

Tags: css, fouc

I have a page with error message hidden using `display: none;`

When page loads, the error message was shown briefly and then went away. It seems ccs applies slowly to the page.

How can I improve the user experience and not allow the error message to display when loading?

The page also loads a table using Ajax call. Could this affect how css applies to the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `style="display:none;"` to the actual html elements or div's on the page that you don't want to show initially.  You can't rely on the CSS file right away.  For example:

```
<div class="error" style="display:none;">
    <span class="myerror">Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

Other than this exception for the hidden areas, it's typically best to keep all your css decoupled from the page and in an external file.

Answer (score 1):

If you call your CSS file with `<link>` then you should try to put your CSS in `<style>` instead. Should be faster. As the external file needs longer to load then `<style>` which you have in the same file.